# Is there any sublime plugin can show the files of the selected directory in a single panel?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3

Sublime can show the directories and files of each in the sidebar, but I'm looking for a plugin that can show the files of the selected dir in a separated panel.

Is there such plugin? Or is it easy to implement such a plugin if no found?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What's wrong with the sidebar, or just keeping your operating system's file manager window open next to Sublime?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just want to focus on the files of a specified folder, sometimes I need to do lot of operations on them